# Having trouble with custom UUID in Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics

I have a problem with using my own generated UUID(not using 16 bit UUID reserved by Bluetooth SIG) to communicate in Android BLE.

Target device is two - one is as a peripheral(Samsung galaxy note 4/android 5.1.1) and another one is as a central(Samsung galaxy S5/android 5.0.1). I put my own service's UUID and characteristic's UUID on the peripheral side. On the central side, it could not find characteristic but service.

It seems like it caused by not using one of [these Characteristic UUIDs](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx) but using custom generated UUID.
Below is my own generated UUIDs.

```
private static final UUID CUSTOM_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("abcd1111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private static final UUID CUSTOM_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("abcd1112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

Service, found well, but characteristic, no.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I found something that if I use UUIDs like this, it works well.  `Service UUID : 000018XX-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Characteristic UUID : 00002AXX-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` ※ XX - any digits              Does it required to use specific number in specific position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using the official base UUID: xxxxxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, from which all upper 32-bit are reserved (some already assigned.)

Instead, you should use your own 128-bit UUID. You can use an [online tool](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) to generate one.  Then just assign your own internal n-bit short uuid to each one of your characteristic.

For example: using base => 18902a9a-1f4a-44fe-936f-14c8eea418xx

- Service => 18902a9a-1f4a-44fe-936f-14c8eea41800
- Characteristic => 18902a9a-1f4a-44fe-936f-14c8eea41801

Comment: Thanks @smertrios but if i use own generated 128-bit UUID, AdvertiseCallback returns error code with `AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE` on `onStartFailure(int errorCode)`.

Comment: @SunggookKim This error is because you have too much data in your advertising payload.  You are limited to a total of 31 bytes within which each piece of data (UUID, name, etc...) is framed using a [byte-length+AD-Type+Data] encoding.  So an 128-bit UUID will take 1+1+16 bytes of payload.  In your case, it looks like you have used up all of your 31-byte payload.  Possible culprit: you are calling setIncludeDeviceName(true) and your device name is too long...