# How to implement a custom UUID for bluetooth broadcast

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I want to change my android device's Bluetooth UUID to a predefined value so that my BLE beacon can recognize it without pairing with it.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986400/having-trouble-with-custom-uuid-in-android-ble) question I gathered that I'll have to change the service UUID but I can't find the relevant documents or tutorials.

How can I achieve this change of UUID via my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Android API documentation?

You use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder#addServiceUuid(android.os.ParcelUuid) function to set a custom service uuid to be advertised.

A general tutorial for advertising can be found here: https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising.